# addEventListener is not working on node

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, nodelist

I have this simple `javascript` code.

```
 var nodeList = document.getElementById(active_tab_selector.attr('id')).getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0, node; node = nodeList[i]; i++) {
node.addEventListener('click', function() {getChild(this.getAttribute(attribute));
                        }, false);
}
```

But the `click` it's not working for some reason, but if I remove `getElementById(active_tab_selector.attr('id'))` it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe there's no element with the "id" value you're passing. Have you checked for that?

Comment: yes when I display the results on console, it is correct.

Comment: Is that code running before the DOM is built? Have you tried adding a `console.log()` call to check at that actual point in the code?

Comment: this code is triggered when I click on some link. so it is after DOM is built and I displayed the results using console.log() they are correct.

Comment: well, are there really any `<span>` elements inside the element with the "id" involved?

Comment: yeah there is a lot of them

Comment: Where and how you get `active_tab_selector`?

Comment: $('.tab-content > div.active'); every element in this code was displayed on the  console for check up and it was  correct.

Comment: If you've got jQuery available, why aren't you doing this code that way? (Also, your jQuery expression refers to the "tab-content" *class*, while your code is looking only at one of them.)

Comment: I want to limit the "AddListenerEvent" to a certain region and not the whole spans on the document, clicks in that region are not functional

Comment: Are *all* clicks not working or do *some of them*?

Comment: in that region none of them

Comment: What happens whith `document.getElementById("typeInCorrectIdofThatRegion").get ...`?

Comment: get a certain region of the code and create a nodeList with the span components

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Try to `type in the correct id as a string` instead of `active_tab_selector.attr('id')`

Comment: I tried, nothing same result

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterate x times for each node but only the last node is valid for callback
then change it by a method that call the addEventListener for node in specific

```
for (var i = 0, node; node = nodeList[i]; i++) {
  addEventTo( node );
}

function addEventTo( node ) {
  node.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    getChild(this.getAttribute(attribute));
  }, false);
}
```

More info about this [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/google-closure-how-not-to-write-javascript/)